# Facebook and Tweetdeck

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, facebook

I've been using [Tweetdeck](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thedeck.android.app&feature=related_apps) in order to post to Twitter and Facebook for a while. It does post my updates on both services, but some of my updates can't be shared. Here is an example (there is no `Share` link):

[image]

I noticed that happens when I my status includes links (I have not tested pictures). Is this some kind of known issue?

Comment: I'd include a `tweetdeck` tag, but I have no reputation to create it.

Comment: How is this related to Android?

Comment: @MatthewRead It's asking about the Android app TweetDeck. Per the FAQ, specific apps are on-topic. (This might not be the best place, but it seems not-wrong to me.)

Comment: @KevinReid It looks like it's asking about Facebook to me, unless apps can tell Facebook to make things unshareable (which I've never heard of -- do you know differently?).

Comment: @MatthewRead It's clearly asking about the Android app Tweetdeck. The clue is in the fact the word Tweetdeck links to the app on the Android market. The Tweetdeck app is posting data to Facebook in a way which gives surprising results. That's what his question is about. Other Android users who use the Tweetdeck app might be able to explain, or suggest a workaround or an alternative. (Technically, it's a question about the implications of which element of Facebook's API the app uses. But neither asker nor answerer would need to know that to give useful answers or input).

Comment: @MatthewRead I'm post this question *because* I do not know where the problem comes from. As @KevinReid said, specific app questions are be on-topic, `Tweetdeck for Android` included.

Comment: OK well I'll give it the benefit of the doubt.